# When asking for definitions: “What is a cat?” or “What are cats?”

Tags: grammar, interrogatives

If I want to ask for the definition of a countable noun(e.g. cat).
Should I say

- “What is a cat?"

or

- “What are cats?”

Are there any difference between the two expressions?

Answer (score 3):

Either can be used. When the plural form is used, the focus is on the characteristics of a group. For example:

> What are people?

asks about the characteristics of a group of people, or of people considered as a collective, while:

> What is a person?

focuses on the definition of an individual person, of a perdson taken in isolation. In some cases the plural will seem more natural, particularly when we often deal with the subject in groups:

> - What are cattle
> - What are dollars?
> - What are bacteria?

In other cases, where we tend to deal with a kind of thing one at a time, the singualr form may seem more natural:

> - What is a building?
> - What is a mood?
> - What is the sun?
> - What is an ocean?

In many cases, either form seems quite natural and one may freely use either, although the response may differ with the form.

Comment: [What are birds? We just don't know.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIVGftIWt4s)

Comment: This is a simple question with a good answer. Now, let's see how we can make it into "big thing". Just expressing a bit of annoyance...